# Как поменять свойство Application Name у TADOConnection в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, adoconnection

Есть Delphi приложение, которое соединяется с БД MS SQL используя TADOConnection. Мне нужно установить значение свойства "Application Name" у этого соединения (чтобы потом иметь его на стороне БД с вот таким запросом: `select distinct program_name from sys.sysprocesses`).

К сожалению, у TADOConnection нету публичного свойства `ApplicationName`. Вместо этого, TADOConnection сам внутри подставляет название исполняемого файла приложения (что можно увидеть выполнив запрос выше).

Как мне установить произвольное значение свойства "Application Name" для TADOConnection соединения с БД MS SQL?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40528195/how-to-set-application-name-property-of-a-tadoconnection-in-delphi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство "Application Name" (а также другие) может быть установлено вот так:

```
AdoConnection1.Properties['Application Name'].Value := 'MyAppName';
```